# Does WPE WebKit support WebAssembly?

Tags: webkit, webassembly, wpe-webkit

Is there a version of WPE WebKit (https://wpewebkit.org) that supports WebAssembly?

Comment: WebAssembly support for it comes from WebKit's own JavaScript engine, JSC, which supports WebAssembly, at least in 64bit CPUs, since a long time ago: https://twitter.com/WebKitGTK/status/885881603888644096

What kind of board/environment are you interested in?